# How can I put a data.frame I made inside a shiny box in R

Tags: r, shiny

Lets suppose I got these two vectors

`letter <- c("a","b")`

`number <- c(1,2)`

And I create a data frame from them:

`data.frame(letter, number)`

Now, I would like to create a box that contains the frame i just created

`library(shinyApp)`

`body <- dashboardBody (box())` I would like to put here inside this box the data.frame

On the other hand, lets say I have this

`plot1 <- barplot(number)`

How can I insert the bars plot inside a shinyApp box?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks @TarJae , I have made some corrections. I hope it now adjusts to the rules.

Answer (score 0):

This is a example how you can render a dataframe as datatable:

```
## your dataframe df
letter <- c("a","b")
number <- c(1,2)
df <- data.frame(letter, number)

# packages you need
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

# ui
ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Sebastian Giraldo Gomez"),
                    sidebar,
                    body
)

# sidebar
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

# body
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
        box(width = 6, 
            title= 'This is my box',
            h2("My first table"),
            DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
            )
    )
  )

# server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    df
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```